resourceTimeGridDay is missing dayHeaderFormat
Im using the fullcalendar schedular v6 plugin.
And i dont really know if its a feature request, bug report or questing if its possible, so im trying stackoverflow first.
The problem is:
When I'm watching the view resourceTimeGridDay, the dayHeaderFormat is simply not rendered.
It would be really nice if I can see the same structure and consistancy in both week view as in day view which is like:
----------------------------------------------------
| WEEK  | MON 7.10   | TUE 8.10  | WED 9.10 |
--------------------------------------------
|       | RESOURCE   | RESOURCE  | RESOURCE |
---------------------------------------------

In the day view im just seing the
----------------------------------------------------
|       | RESOURCE   | RESOURCE  | RESOURCE |
---------------------------------------------

fullCalendar weekly view:

Is that not possible to get the Week and date even for day view? Because I'm also using the header.
What I have tried so far:
I have been checking the source code to figure out if there is some settings, but I just came to I need to search for the classname presentation and unfortunately it left me nowhere.
I cannot really see what is causing the dayHeaderFormat not to be rendered in resourceTimeGridDay format. Is that by design or is it a bug?
I have the following configuration:
    views: {
        timeGridTwoDay: {
            type: 'timeGrid',
            duration: { days: 2 },
            buttonText: '2 days',
        },
        resourceTimeGridTwoDay: {
            type: 'resourceTimeGrid',
            duration: { days: 2 },
            buttonText: '2 days',
            dayHeaderFormat: {
                weekday: 'long', year: 'numeric', month: 'short', day: 'numeric',
            },
        },
        resourceTimeGridDay: {
            dayHeaderFormat: {
                weekday: 'long', year: 'numeric', month: 'short', day: 'numeric',
            },
        },
    },

But when I check the Chrome element inspector the row with the week is simply not rendered.
Related issues:
I can see its rather related tickets of the same matter, but I dont really feel they are concluded, that's why I'm bringing this up:
Fullcalendar V5 : dayHeaders are not visible in resourceTimeGridDay view
However, the reason why I would really like it is because we are injecting the weather forecast into the date, and without that date, I need to do redundant code that will take account for if the header is either in the title or if the date is in the header.
I would be very nice to be able to view the date row for day view as well as weekly views, to keep some consistancy in the calendar, and not things are different places dependent on your view.
Also, according to this post:
Show day header in timeline fullcalendar
It is possible in the timeline view, but its not in the timeGrid.

This is by design. It's a single-day view. What would be the purpose of re-stating the same date which is already 1cm above it in the page (i.e. in the calendar header)? It would look silly. I agree your weather forecast idea is good, but for day views I think you'll have to find somewhere else to put it.

If you disagree, and would at least like to add the option for this, the documentation for how to request features is here: https://fullcalendar.io/requesting-features

It is possible in the timeline view, but its not in the timeGrid...because in timeline the view is inverted, so those are slots (which are on the side in the timeGrid, but on the top in the timeline). It's a different component of the calendar, controlled by a different setting.

The purpose is to have consistency, I can see it's possible in the normal day grid, but not in the resource day grid, and it seems to be the only field which is actually week aware, which is highly relevant on day view.
In the title format, I can actually not add the week number, I have to create custom javascript for that, that I have already done.
But I will go on for the feature request :)
